# How to split a string via regex in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a really long string (it's a log to be exact), which, is not broken up by line breaks. However, I do know that each entry starts with a timestamp

Example string:

```
2019-11-11 hey Boy 2019-11-12 hey Girl 2019-11-13 Super star DJs 2019-11-14 Here we go
```

I would like to format this into an array like below in JavaScript:

```
array(
[0] => '2019-11-11 hey Boy'
[1] => '2019-11-12 hey Girl' 
[2] => '2019-11-13 Super star DJs'
[3] => '2019-11-14 Here we go'
)
```

I've tried doing `string.split(/([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})/)` but that just extracts the first date.

Any ideas how to use a regex to match a pattern to split a long string at?

Comment: split on `\s+(?=[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})` - use a lookahead to capture positions before dates

Comment: If there are no dates inside the log line data, then splitting with a lookahead is a solution. It may be safer to use `split(/\s+(?=\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}(?!-?\d))/)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Split the string on the white-space before each date and put the date in a lookahead.

```
string.split(/\s+(?=[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})/)
```

That means: *one or more white-spaces followed by a date*

A lookahead assertion doesn't consume characters, it's only a test.